# Parallel job submission of for loop

Tags: bash, parallelism, batch-jobs, platform-lsf

I have written `for` loop and parallelized it with `&` and limited the threshold to running `3` jobs at one time. Below is my script. I am reserving `32 cores` and `256 GB` memory through `BSUB` command. The `sample_pipe` I am running inside `for` loop requires `32` cores and `256 GB` memory.

I am getting memory failure errors on some jobs. I think I am reserving only `32` cores and `256 GB` and trying to run `3` jobs at a time which might be causing memory failure errors on some jobs.

My question is how do I parallelize such that all `3` jobs are using the same amount of cores and memory.

I submitted using the command `bsub < example.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
#BSUB -J cnt_job            # LSF job name
#BSUB -o cnt_job.%J.out     # Name of the job output file
#BSUB -e cnt_job.%J.error   # Name of the job error file
#BSUB -n 32                 # 32 cores
#BSUB -M 262144             # 256 GB
#BSUB -R "span[hosts=1] rusage [mem=262144]"

n=0
maxjobs=3
for sample in $main ; do
     for run in $nested ; do
             sample_pipe count --id="$run_name" \
             --localcores=32 \
             --localmem=256 &
     done
     cd ..
     # limit jobs
    if (( $(($((++n)) % $maxjobs)) == 0 )) ; then
        wait # wait until all have finished
        echo $n wait
    fi
done
```

Comment: for those not in the know: is this an actual, normal, Bash script, or some similar-looking thing that's interpreted by some other tool, using some other rules? In particular, `for sample in main` would just run one iteration of the loop, so the script looks a bit confusing.

Comment: Its an example. Some similar-looking script.

Comment: You are explicitly launching three jobs and giving each 32 cores and 256G of ram. I don't quite see what you are expecting here. Perhaps you meant to give each of your jobs 32/3 =~ 10 CPUs?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I have had memory issues on some jobs and thought each job was not receiving 32 cores and 256G.

Comment: Would it be ideal to distribute each job across different nodes?. If so can you suggest how to do it?

Comment: Can you check the available resources before start any new process? Wait until you have enough. (example: max cpu:20 max mem 100G, min cpu 5 min mem 30. If you have more than a maximum -> use the maximum, otherwise use less, if the resources under the minimum limit -> wait....)

Comment: I think this would be ideal in my case. But, I am not sure how to achieve this. Can you please tell me how do I do this in my script? Maybe posting it as an answer if possible.

Comment: You seem to be using some sort of queuing system that manages resources (that's what the `#BSUB` lines look like). Have you considered giving it one script per process, instead of looping over  `$main` and letting it take care of the rest? That's basically the whole idea of such systems. Most have their own tools for looping, but you would have to talk to whoever is responsible for this cluster.

Comment: About submitting it one script per process: You meant one script can be used to distribute the ```samples``` present in ```$main``` as different processes?. Also, Yes, I will talk to the administrator. Thanks!